# Print the next page - java script

Tags: javascript, printing

Is it possible to print the page to where the link is directed? I have many short information on one site. I would like to print whole article by clicking on the link that is on the first site. Every link has an unique id. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is a [`window.print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print) method that opens browser's print window, but for obvious security reasons you can't tell it what exactly to print from JavaScript.

You still can somehow retrieve this page server-side and serve it along with call to `window.print`, but this would have obvious drawbacks too.

Answer (score 0):

The browser would have to load the next page to print it.

If there is a link for printing, you can load the page into a hidden iframe and print that.

If it is just the normal browser print, you are probably out of luck unless you try to do some sort of synchronous Ajax call with print events that are not well supported.